# Numerically finding confidence interval bounds

Tags: r, simulation, cumulative-distribution-function

I am asking an R question here on the basis that statistical expertise is needed, i.e.,

> If the language is statistically oriented (such as R, SAS, Stata,
>   SPSS, etc.), then decide based on the nature of your question: if it
>   needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here

I have a symmetric (about some value $\mu$) probability density function $f$ with support in $(-\infty, \infty)$. Let's suppose, for simplicity's sake, that it's the normal distribution $$f(x; \mu, \sigma) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2/2\right]\text{.}$$
Ignoring the fact that there's a `dnorm` function in R, let's say I wrote this out as a function:

```
f <- function(x, mu, sigma){
1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-mu)/sigma)^2/2)
}
```

I would like to solve the equation
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x; \mu, \sigma)\text{ d}x = \pi \in [0, 1]\text{ fixed.}$$
where $\mu = \dfrac{a+b}{2}$, for $a$ and $b$.

Without standardizing the normal distribution and without using any of the "normal"-supplied functions in R (e.g., `dnorm`, `pnorm`, `qnorm`, `rnorm` and related functions), how do I solve for $a$ and $b$ in R?

Here's what I do know:

1. R has an integrating function. But I'm not sure how to use this to help me solve for the bounds.
2. The normal distribution PDF, along with the PDF of distribution I am working with, do not have closed forms for the CDF.

I would guess that simulation is involved, but I wouldn't know where to start.

(Note: I know this seems silly, but I would like to know how this works for the normal distribution so that I can extend it to a general PDF.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use integrate to evaluate the integral and then e.g. uniroot to solve $\int_{\mu-a}^{\mu+a} f(x)dx - \pi = 0$ as follows (n.b. I changed the parameterisation slightly):

```
f <- function(x, mu, sigma) {
    1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-((x-mu)/sigma)^2/2)
}

g<-function(a,mu,sigma,p) {
    integrate(function(x){f(x,mu,sigma)}, mu-a, mu+a)$value - p
}

uniroot(g, interval=c(-10,10), mu=0,sigma=1, p =0.95)$root
```

Output:

```
[1] 1.959969
```

Note that the (-10,10) is the search interval.  Check ?uniroot for more info.

*N.b. no need for simulation.  Also, even if a closed form solution is not available, many distributions have good numerical approximations to their inverses.*

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with R. 
But a (simple) solution is based on Monte Carlo:
You can draw n samples from the distribution.

With the following algorithm you can find a and b:

- Divide the samples in two equally sized arrays:
- the samples greater as the median (gm) and
- the samples lower than the median (lm).
- to get a : sort (lm) descent. a is approximate the value of the $n * \pi/2$-item ($\pi$ is the value of the total integral)
- analog for b: sorting order asc

Comment: I'm sorry, how does this help me find the interval $[a, b]$?

Comment: I updated my answer, because I misunderstood your question the first time.